# Google Sheet - Query - Line Break

Tags: google-sheets-formula, line-breaks

I have this query formula:

```
IF(A8="","",IFNA(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,QUERY(Sheet6!B5:K,"SELECT F, I, J, K WHERE C = DATE'" & TEXT(A8,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "' AND G = 2",0)))))
```

It uses `TEXTJOIN` to return the values in a *single cell* like this:

```
A1, B1, C1, D1, A2, B2, C2, D2, A3, B3, C3, D3
```

I want this to remain in a single cell, but for the cell to show with line breaks as follows:

```
A1, B1, C1, D1
A2, B2, C2, D2
A3, B3, C3, D3
```

A1, A2 and A3 are names and contain spaces.

How can I adjust this to match the 2nd excerpt? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look into `CHAR(10)`. This will insert line breaks. Without an example sheet I am not going to recreate your setup to provide a formula that I am not sure will work.

Comment: I tried CHAR(10) but I am unable to break the line at the intended point. I'll create a sample sheet and share shortly.

Comment: @KevinP. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W2qZ6pl1C5C6bByFXLlFvGPbU0xPgTQSYB8wkqUOXEE/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a Regular expression to replace every 4th comma with the `CHAR(10)` value. This is what I believe you are looking for:

`=REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, QUERY(Sheet6!B5:K, "SELECT F, I, J, K WHERE C = DATE'" & TEXT(A8, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' AND G = 2", 0)),"((?:[^,]*,){3}[^,]*), ", "$1"&CHAR(10))`

- **(?:[^,]*,){3}** This part matches any sequence of characters followed by a comma, repeated exactly 3 times.
- **[^,]*** This matches the characters after the 3rd comma until the next comma.
- **,**  This matches the 4th comma. Including a space to account for the `,` .
- The **$1** that we replace the comma with preserves the content after the comma.

Comment: Can you explain the last part of the formula?

Comment: Yes, the regular expression we use `((?:[^,]*,){3}[^,]*), ` captures the content in the 3rd field within a comma separated list. So in a "field1, field2, field3, field4" string the expression will capture "field3". The **"$1" & CHAR(10)** is the replacement string. **$1** refers to the content captured by the first capturing group in the regular expression. **CHAR(10)** is the newline character, which is used to insert a line break after the captured content. So, the replacement effectively adds a line break after the third field.

Comment: A little difficult to grasp now but with regular usage it should become easy. I will also try a few variations to understand it better. Thank you so much.

Comment: Check out this link: https://regexr.com/ and input the regular expression. Then type out some text such as `Here, is , some, text, separated, by, commas` and mouse over elements. Not perfect, but helps a lot.